How to Create a Scatter Plot of Proportion of Behavior versus Group Size in R using ggplot2?
I'm trying to visualize the relationship between the proportion of a specific behavior and group size for multiple observations (i have 3000 data points for n = 140 individuals) using a scatter plot in R. I have data where I've measured the proportion of this behavior for different group sizes, and I want to see if there's any trend or correlation between these variables.
Here's an example of my data structure:
Group Size: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Proportion of Behavior: [0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55]

I've been using the ggplot2 package for data visualization in R, but I'm unsure how to create a scatter plot specifically for this scenario i created a plot

but it is not clearly explaining the relationship. Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this using ggplot2? Additionally, if there are any considerations or best practices I should be aware of when plotting proportions versus continuous variables like group size, I'd appreciate any advice on that as well.
